# Unable to deploy locally trained Logistic Regression model on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, logistic-regression, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a Logistic Regression model on my local machine. Saved the model using Joblib and tried deploying it on Aws Sagemaker using "Linear-Learner" image.

Facing issues while deployment as the deployment process keeps continuing and the Status is always as "Creating" and does not turn to "InService".

```
endpoint_name = "DEMO-LogisticEndpoint" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
print(endpoint_name)
create_endpoint_response = sm_client.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name, EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name
)
print(create_endpoint_response["EndpointArn"])

resp = sm_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
status = resp["EndpointStatus"]
print("Status: " + status)

while status == "Creating":
    time.sleep(60)
    resp = sm_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    status = resp["EndpointStatus"]
    print("Status: " + status)
```

The while loop keeps executing and the status never change.

Answer (score 0):

Background: What is important to understand is that the endpoint runs a container that includes the serving software. Each container expects a certain type of model. You need to make sure you're model and how you package it matches what the container expects.

Two easy paths forward:

1. Linear-learner is a SageMaker built-in algorithm, so a straight forward path would be to train it in the cloud. See [example](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/breast_cancer_prediction/Breast%20Cancer%20Prediction.html), making it very easy to deploy.
2. Use Scikit-learn Logistic Regression][2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), which you can [train locally and deploy to SageMaker using the scikit-learn container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sklearn.html) ([XGBoost](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/xgboost_customer_churn/xgboost_customer_churn.html) is another easy path).

Otherwise, you can always go more advanced and use any custom algorithm by bringing your own custom algorithm/framework by[bringing your own container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-byoc-containers.html). Google for existing implementations (e.g., [CatBoost/SageMaker](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-byo-catboost-container-demo)).